# Python using recursion to take a mixed string and add up the integers in the string

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to use recursion to take a mixed string and add the values on the integers. An example input would be "ab4h5h6" and the out put would be 15.

Here is my code so far

```
def toNumber(s):
    total = 0
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        first = s[0]
        rest = s[1:]
        num_rest = toNumber(s[1:])
        if first.isdigit()== True:
            return int(first) + total
        else:
            if rest.isdigit()== True:
                return int(rest) + int(num_rest)
```

I have tried many different things but I just can't seem to get the desired result.

Comment: Please never use `== True` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to care if the `rest` is a digit; just add the value of `first` (which is 0 if not a digit) plus the recursive result:

```
def toNumber(s):
    if not s:
        return 0

    first = s[0]
    value = int(first) if first.isdigit() else 0
    return value + toNumber(s[1:])
```

Other notes:

- Empty strings are 'falsey'; so `not s` is only true if the string is empty. `len(s) == 0` can thus be reduced to `not s`.
- There is no need to use `== True` on boolean tests, that is what `if` already does for you.

Demo:

```
>>> def toNumber(s):
...     if not s:
...         return 0
...     first = s[0]
...     value = int(first) if first.isdigit() else 0
...     return value + toNumber(s[1:])
...
>>> toNumber('ab4h5h6')
15
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfect. I was thinking way too into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The very shortest :

`toNumber = lambda s: bool(s) and ((s[0].isdigit() and int(s[0])) + toNumber(s[1:]))`

If you don't need recursion :

`toNumber = lambda s: sum(int(i) for i in s if i.isdigit())`

or even one character shorter, although less pythonic :

`toNumber = lambda s: sum(map(int,filter(str.isdigit,s))))`

Comment: IMHO by far the best answer here. BTW using `map` and `filter` is not only less Pythonic, it's also (in Python 2) wasting memory by creating two unnecessary lists.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I should have more explained my code, but I don't like to, because it thus forces people to do some research :(
And yes, allowing decent functional programming is really one of the improvements of Python 3!

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating things. The recursion should always be to return the number value of the current character plus the result of the function called on the rest of the string:

```
def toNumber(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0

    first = s[0]
    rest = s[1:]

    numFirst = 0
    if first.isdigit():
        numFirst = int(first)

    return num_first + toNumber(rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution.

Strategy: recklessly treat each number as an int and catch the exceptions

```
def toNumber(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    try:
        return int(s[:1]) + toNumber(s[1:])
    except ValueError:
        return toNumber(s[1:])
```

And here's a non-recursive version employing the same strategy

```
def toNumberNonRecursive(s):
    total = 0
    for c in s:
        try:
            total += int(c)
        except ValueError:
            # not an int
            pass

    return total
```

Output:

```
>>> print(toNumber('1a2b3c'))
6
>>> print(toNumber(''))
0
>>> print(toNumber('abc'))
0
>>> print(toNumber('w48957jmc98(&H(*&398cmdi98'))
87
```